# (Cache::lock()) -> get() -- Under what conditions does it return false?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking into using the `Cache::lock` mechanism with laravel, but something isn't exactly clear to me.

This is the example they use:

```
$lock = Cache::lock('foo', 10);

if ($lock->get()) {
    // Lock acquired for 10 seconds...

    $lock->release();
}
```

Now, it's my understanding that under NORMAL conditions, if the lock is still in place when `$lock->get()` is called, it will wait for the previous lock to be released before continuing on. Is that correct? (that seems like the whole point of a lock to me, so I certainly hope that's correct).

If that is correct, then what would ever make `$lock->get()` return false? Would it return false if it expects the wait time to be over 10 seconds, or something like that?

Comment: " it will wait for the previous lock to be released before continuing on. Is that correct?" No it will not wait.  in your code how it's written now will always return true.

Comment: well it won't ALWAYS return true. If 2 requests come in that both lock 'foo' at the same time, the first one `$lock->get()` seems to return true, and the second one false, as long as `$lock-release()` wasn't called in the first request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy to find something in the laravel docs and in the sources about this. What I've been able to gather is that the call to `Cache::lock` does not acquire it, it seems to only define what is able to be locked.

The calls to `get()` and `block()` seem to do the actual acquiring.

My assumptions are as follows:

- `Cache::lock(foo, n)` will create a new lock on `foo` that can be held for a maximum of `n` seconds
- `$lock->get()` will try to acquire it and return false if it was already held by someone else.
- `$lock->block(n)` will try to acquire it and block for a maximum of `n` seconds, if it fails to acquire during this time, it will throw `LockTimeoutException`

You should test if it actually follows this behavior though as I'm not able to confirm this.

---

For reference:

- [Laravel Lock docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#accessing-tagged-cache-items)
- [Illuminate/Cache/Lock.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a083ab775cdcaaa4cdf51f157d3da74dff854df1/src/Illuminate/Cache/Lock.php#L88-L133)

Comment: So `$lock->get()` doesn't wait at all, but `$lock->block()` does?

Comment: @TKoL yes, (if my assumption is correct but that would make the most sense)

Comment: Reading the code in Lock.php for block and get, it seems you're right. Block goes through a sleep loop where it checks the lock apparently every quarter-second until it gets it, erroring if it can't get it in the number of seconds specified. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm so stupid. If I just read the rest of the section on the Laravel docs, it gives an example of using `->block()` to wait. [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#managing-locks)

Answer (score 1):

The calls of `$lock->get()` also do lock. Just try this code

```
Log::info('checkpoint 2 ' .  $lock->owner() . " - get? " . ($lock->get() ? "true" : "false") );
Log::info('checkpoint 2A ' .  $lock->owner() . " - get? " . ($lock->get() ? "true" : "false") );
```

It would return

```
[2022-05-12 22:41:11] production.INFO: checkpoint 2 l5qJhOOORy1nNFHt - get? true
[2022-05-12 22:41:11] production.INFO: checkpoint 2A l5qJhOOORy1nNFHt - get? false
```

From above result, we can know that the first `$lock->get()` will get return boolean true, and the second `$lock->get()` would get return boolean false. It is indicate the `$lock->get()` also do some locking thread until you do `$lock->release()` or `$lock->forceRelease()`

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#managing-locks) doesn't mentioned about this and hopefully it would help others.

Comment: That's not what happened for me. I got true for both lines. My understanding is that if you try to acquire the lock twice from the same process, it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

`Cache::lock('foo', 10)->get(function () {});` **will not wait** for the locked cache to become available. If it isn't available, the rest of your code continues.

`Cache::lock('foo', 10)->block(5, function () {});` **will wait** for the lock to be open before continuing: (based on my testing and the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#managing-locks))

```php
Cache::lock('foo', 10)->block(5, function () {
    // Lock acquired after waiting a maximum of 5 seconds...
    // Do things...
});
// Code down here will only run after the locked cache is acquired
// and your closure function has executed, or 5 seconds have passed
// and the lock was not acquired.
```

You may also write this as:

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\LockTimeoutException;
 
$lock = Cache::lock('foo', 10);
 
try {
    $lock->block(5);
 
    // Lock acquired after waiting a maximum of 5 seconds...
} catch (LockTimeoutException $e) {
    // Unable to acquire lock...
} finally {
    $lock?->release();
}
```

Laravel 10.x: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#managing-locks